# Fixing SQL injection in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a predicate that is built using the following string

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayName == [cd] %@ AND emailAddress == [cd] %@" , displayName, emailAddress];
```

Periodically when running my application I'm getting a trap with the following cause:

```
Fatal Exception   NSInvalidArgumentException
unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (0x64b5580 <x-coredata://3AA31AFB-35E4-468C-876D-03DEB56F38A3/aaa/p14> IN )
```

It would appear that the problem is caused by injection of valid SQL into the predicate statement.

Is the recommended workaround here to use a predicate with the following format?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(displayName == [cd] \"%@\") AND (emailAddress == [cd] \"%@\")" , displayName, emailAddress];
```

i.e. to surround the search targets with double quotes? Or is some other approach recommended here?

Comment: Can you verify if the `displayName` and `emailAddress` is valid when the exception is raised. The placeholder inserts the quotes for the values so there is no need for including  superfluous quotes.

Comment: I wish I could but I just have crashlytics data. You're right about the quotes being there - I just validated that myself. I need to find the input data that leads to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure about the integrity of the values, try to use the `NSCompoundPredicate`. Add a predicate to an predicate array only if the value is valid and create an `AND` compound predicate from the predicate array

```
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

if (displayName) {
    [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayName == [cd] %@",displayName]];
}

if (emailAddress) {
    [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailAddress == [cd] %@",emailAddress]];
}

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

Comment: Thanks this looks nice - the data is coming from email addresses / names that come from an email server so they could be anything.